# Is it possible to consume messages when one of Kafka nodes is down?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I get the following error when trying to run Spark Streaming job with Kafka:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leaders for Set([<topicName>,1])
```

I was reading that this error might occur because one of the Kafka nodes is down. So, I checked it and it's really the case: among 3 nodes, 1 of them is down. My question is if it's possible to configure (from the Scala code) the Kafka consumer in such a way that even when some nodes are down, it still works? It has to do with the replication factor (should be greater than 1, as far as I understand), but not sure how to set it from the code:

```
val eEventsMap = eventsTopic.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> "172.135.23.25:9092,172.135.23.35:9092,172.135.23.45:9092",
                                      "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")
val events = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, eventsMap).map(_._2)
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to Scala or Spark, you need to set the replication factor for the topic to be more than 1.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Thank you. How to set it? Is it possible to set it from code or should I set it somewhere else? Then problem is that I cannot change the configuration of Kafka because I am working on the cluster, in which the administrator defined all the configurations. I can only change settings from the code.

Comment: The topic has the following settings: `{"name":"test-events","configs":{},"partitions":[{"partition":0,"leader":1,"replicas":[{"broker":1,"leader":true,"in_sync":true},{"broker":2,"leader":false,"in_sync":true},{"broker":0,"leader":false,"in_sync":true}]}]}`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Ok, I see that it's possible to create a topic (using `kafka-topics.sh`) with the parameter `replication-factor`. However, I have another issue: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed`. What does it all mean?! Is it related to the usage of `createDirectStream` and firewall?